# How do I set interval for one div and deactive interval for other divs?

Tags: javascript

How do I approach this?
Say I have a number of divs.
An on click event triggers animation causing this very div to flicker. When I click on another div that one starts flickering but previous one stops flickering. How do I stop the previous ones from flickering when the new one starts flickering?

Comment: please attach some code

Answer (score 0):

You should set your interval to a variable like `const divInterval = setInterval()` and then when you want to clear it just run `clearInterval(divInterval);`

If you want to have a few running concurrently and then want to stop them all you could save them in an array, then loop over them and just run the same `clearInterval()` method.